# How to change HTML text only?

Tags: jquery, html, string, text

How to change this?

```
<p>Please change me</p>
```

Can I change "Please change me" without using `replaceWith("<p>This is been changed.</p>")`?
`replaceWith()` is changing the whole HTML content including the `<p>` tag.

Is there a way to get the "Please change me" only? And not including the `<p>` tag... then change it to something like "This is been changed."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `id` for your `<p>`, and use the [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method:

```
<p id="needed">Please change me</p>
$('#needed').text('new text');
```

Comment: +1, The other answers apply the text change to all paragraphs.

Comment: @Nicolae Albu `clone wars` on the page

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this won't work as expected if #needed has child elements.

Comment: @Ezequiel, yes, because you should pass the correct path to element you want to edit in `$('#needed')`.

Answer (score 3):

Just do

```
// I'm just changing the text content
$('p').text('This has been changed.');
```

or even

```
$('p').html('This has been changed.');
```

The latter should really be used only if your content contains HTML markup, for example:

```
$('p').html('<span>This has been <strong>changed</strong></span>.');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('p').html('changed')
```

'nuff said

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
    $('p').text('me');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('p').text('This has been changed')
```

You can go to look up the jQuery API.